# Selecting from a joined connecting table only if it hasn't already been selected

Tags: mysql

I have three tables - p, m, and i. M is a connecting table for p and i, and has a distance attribute to determine how far away i is from p. What I want to do is select all of i for each p if it hasn't already been selected for a previous p. Since you can't call select distinct for only one column, I'm slightly confused as to what I could do. Right now my query is as follows (hopefully still easy to follow as I attempt to make it a little vague):

```
select p.id, p.name, m.distance, i.id from p join m on p.id=m.p_id join i on m.i_id=i.id where m.distance <= 30 order by p.name;
```

Basically, I only want i associated to p if it's not closer to another p (which would be determined by m.distance). There are many i items that are further than 30, I don't want those at all.

Been beating my head against this for an hour now. I would greatly appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group by i.id in order to have distinct values of this column in the result.

But first, to make sure you are getting the i with the smallest distance to p, I would recommend you first do a select and order by distance like this:

```
select p.id, p.name, m.distance, i.id 
from p join m on p.id=m.p_id join i on m.i_id=i.id 
where m.distance <= 30 order by m.distance asc
```

This previous query will return all the Is that are connected to p ordered by distance from smallest to largest.

Then you can do a select on the result returned by the previous query and group by i.id. The group by will act as a distinct on the i.id column that will return the first line found(the smallest) if there are multiple i.id:

```
select * from (select p.id, p.name as p_name, m.distance, i.id as idOfI 
from p join m on p.id=m.p_id join i on m.i_id=i.id 
where m.distance <= 30 order by m.distance asc) as ordredIs 
group by idOfI 
order by p_name
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out and came here to check if I was accurate, and got the same answer you did. I also select min(distance) as distance on my outer query to ensure mysql selects the closest i when there are multiple. From what I read, it can sometimes select one at random when you use a group by, and I wanted to make sure it didn't. Maybe I'm wrong and that's a waste of SQL, but it solved my problem all the same. Thank you for your response.